# matching multi line string with shell(regex + order )

Tags: regex, shell

I want to search bellow given string match with file text

```
[zero or more white-space]AA[one or more white-space]AA[zero or more white-space]
[zero or more white-space]BB[one or more white-space]BB[zero or more white-space]
```

matching lines should be correct order

note :not correct order

```
BB    BB

other lines

AA AA
```

No duplicate matching

note : duplicate line matching

```
  AA AA

 AA    AA
```

in between 'AA AA' and 'BB BB' zero or more lines(any string) can contain

```
find=$(grep -e "\(^[[:space:]]*AA [[:space:]]*AA[[:space:]]*$\|[[:space:]]*BB [[:space:]]*BB[[:space:]]*\)" myfile.txt | grep -oP '^[[:space:]]*AA[[:space:]]*AA[[:space:]]*\s+[[:space:]]*BB[[:space:]]*BB[[:space:]]*$')
duplicate=$(sort $in_file | uniq -d | (grep "\(^ *AA \+AA *$\|^ *BB \+BB *$\)") )

if [[ -z $duplicate ]] && [[ ! -z $find ]] ; then
  echo 'OK'
else
  echo 'NOT OK'
fi
```

above script work fine if string have spaces `AA[space]AA` but if there is space with tab like `AA[space][tab]AA` not work

problem with i can't give \s+ with `grep -oP`

Comment: use the character class `[[:blank:]]` (that contains the tab too) instead of `[[:space:]]`, or if it is possible use an ASCII character class like this one: `[ \t]`